# Does the Minolta Hi Matic 7 need batteries to function?

Tags: film, battery, minolta, film-cameras

I bought myself my first film camera, and I am wondering if Minolta Hi Matic 7 will take pictures without a battery.
I wonder, because I've seen posts that say some film cameras don't really need batteries to work. I want to know if my Minolta Hi Matic 7 is one of those. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't *require* batteries, although there are drawbacks to using the camera without them.

The battery powers the camera's light meter. This means you will not be able to shoot in auto without a battery. You could shoot manually, but this would mean metering must be done either by guestimating, using the [sunny 16 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunny_16_rule), or by the use of an external light meter.

You are right some cameras do need batteries to function properly. The similar Yashica Electro 35, for example, will shoot only at 1/500th if left without batteries. This Yashica can't be used to shoot manual (it lacks a shutter ring).

Enjoy your new camera!

Comment: Ha, nice edit @mattdm. Edited the OP to such an extent, my post no longer made sense!

Comment: Yeah happens all the time :)